# Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, select

I create following function

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fn_test_Select (@mat varchar)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
    SELECT * 
    from zMatnrJson 
    where matnr = @mat
```

but execution of

```
SELECT dbo.fn_test_Select('test')
```

returns following error

> Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fn_test_Select", or the name is ambiguous.

Can you explain what's wrong with my function definition?

Comment: You need a statement like `SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_test_Select('test')` when the UDF returns a table.

Comment: Also `varchar` without any length is equivalent to `varchar(1)` in this context

Comment: So obvious... I'm tired! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The function you defined returns a query, not a scalar. You need to query from it, not have it as a column:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   dbo.fn_test_Select('test')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a table-valued function, so you simply need a different `SELECT` statement to get the expected results.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.fn_test_Select('test')
```

Your actual statement consumes the result from a scalar-valued function and this is the reason for the returned error message. Also, as @MartinSmith mentioned in the comment, using `varchar` without a length is equal to `varchar(1)` when you use a data definition or variable declaration statement and is equal to `varchar(30)` in `CAST()` and `CONVERT()` functions. You need to change the parameter definition and use the appropriate length.